# Count Bytes by Ports

Tags: linux, iptables, tcp

Using RHEL/CentOS 6.7 -- I want to be be able to know byte counts on IPv4 ports.  We have thousands.. I would *think* counting via IP Tables for that would be a bit unweldy and slow the firewall a wee bit.  I guess Linux does not keep a running total of the bytes/port in /proc somewhere.

I've been looking at ss, netstat, iptraf and netlink.  They don't give me what I'm looking for... is this information already available or am I going to have to setup firewall counters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iptables by default (in my experience) counts packets matched against its rules, you don't need to setup this up.
By default this is reset when you reboot, but I believe you can setup something up to remember the count.
Because this is happening anyway I can't see how you are going to be "slowing down the firewall", you are only querying iptables for information that has already been obtained.

To view iptables current packet / byte count:

```
[sudo] iptables -nvL | grep -v '0    0'
```

#### Explanation

- `-n` - dont do DNS lookups
- `-L` - list rules - by default shows all chains (on filter table)
- `-v` - this is what gives the matching info and byte counts

By default the nvL command shows all the rules that are defined even if there are 0 counts of matches, so the `grep -v` just removes these lines.

If you want something a little more "in real time" you can wrap the command in a watch statement

```
watch "[sudo] iptables -nvL | grep -v '0    0'"
```

Comment: I understand -- but I'd have to create rules by port.  So I have 350 integrations, each one is using a different port to communicate.  So to get a tally of bytes that each port would be a separate firewall rule.

Comment: @Ziferius ok I see. so you are saying you dont have rules that explicitly ACCEPT legitimate traffic? what I mean is, wouldn't you have a policy that `DROP`'s everything - and only `ACCEPT` what you want - so I would have thought you would have those rules anyway? if not you might be able to build an AWK script which reads iptables packet counts and aggregates per port - or if creating per port rules is an option and the port numbering has some "regular" system - use a script to assign the rules...?

Answer (score 1):

Is this interactive? I use [`iptraf`](http://iptraf.seul.org/) for this.

[image: iptraf screenshot]

Try:

```
    # yum install iptraf
```

Comment: No; it would not be interactive.  The bytes it counts; are when you start the program -- I would want a running total of bytes per day by port.

Comment: then try  `iptraf -B -s eth0 -t 1 -L /root/test.log`

Comment: I've looked at that.  But this would be running 24/7 -- iptraf logs the data and potentially slows things down like tcpdump does by putting the interface in promiscuous mode.